# Boost requires compiled libraries like libboost_date_time for even basic things. How do I eliminate dependencies on building those libraries?

Tags: boost

I want a header-only BOOST.

Using `boost::bind` and `boost::ptr_set`, it seems unnecessary to depend on `libboost_date_time` and `libboost_regex`. But I get a linker error for those libraries when I build.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-s-1_47.lib'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geenrally you can `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to disable the auto-linking of the MSVC compiler you are using as documented (see [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/index.html#boost_config.configuring_boost_for_your_platform.user_settable_options)). But of course you still have to compile and link the libraries you do use. Which if you are getting those errors it means that you are likely using the libraries.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it complained, but the software works without these libs without issues anyway. Thanks for the complete answer from the docs.

Answer (score 4):

`#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB` in your compiler Makefile to exclude the `datetime` library. `#define BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB` to exclude the `regex` library, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the bcp utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) to copy the specific portions of Boost that you actually use.